# How to fetch list of response from login post api and display in another page in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

responseCode: "00", responseDesc: "Login successful", timestamp: "2022-06-24T09:18:33.965",…}
data: {accountNumbers: ["98765432102"], cifNumber: "87654",…}
accessToken: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJleHAiOjU5NjE3NTMwNDk5ODYwMDAsImlhdCI6MTY1NjA0MjUxMywidXNlcmluZm8iOiJ0ZXN0dXNlciJ9.Yx3yzkQwYlPUmqeWodFcuy6ivHjYFUwejVwlDDepvDUsgLyJTCAeis2EyDQE7LUpL3JBfnRZcNu9B0_Vq643WQ"
accountNumbers: ["98765432102"]
0: "98765432102"
cifNumber: "87654"
responseCode: "00"
responseDesc: "Login successful"
timestamp: "2022-06-24T09:18:33.965"

```
          This is my reponse for login page how to fetch account number from this reponse and display it in drop down in another page.
```

Comment: There's no way to answer this question. You need to post some code that you have tried already. Post your html and javascript -- then maybe someone can help you

Comment: use a website like jsfiddle or pastebin to create a test page so that other people can see what code you have so far